# float format variable with integer value in string

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I was facing with one minor issue, and I'm wondering: Why?

here we have some string:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat@"%.3f/%.3f/%.3f/%i", 1.0, 1.0, 1, 1];
```

in this case, result is 1.000/1.000/1/*abra-kadabra like 34875689*.
Why it's happens? Of course, I know, when we change the third value to 1.0, then everything will be okay. 
So, please, explain me the deep proces of this operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you wrote `%f`, the compiler expects a `float` but recognizes an `int`. Writing `1` instead of `1.0` tells the compiler it's an integer constant instead of `1.0`, which is a float constant.

Comment: Yes. everything is correct. But, I'm wondering, why it has bad influence on fourth value, in this case. +1

Comment: oh OK, I would assume that the compiler stores the 4 values right next to each other without storing information about their type. so when during run time the format string is being filled it just takes the format indicators and their corresponding number of bytes to fill them. since an integer is represented with fewer bytes than a float it gets confused and simply takes some rubbish from memory to fill the specified floats...

Comment: hm. It seems to be true. byt it's quite stange.